# Getting a complete list of EC2 Instances available in AWS by any API or JSON Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to know how to get a list of the EC2 Instances available in AWS making a JSON/XML Request or using any API of AWS.

**Case**:

"I want to display in my app the EC2 Instances available in AWS and also use this data to suggest an EC2 Instances"

Any idea?

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**
The list of EC2 Instances that i would like to display and use is the one that appears in : http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: Do you mean EC2 instance types or running EC2 instances? Here is the EC2 API reference FWIW - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Comment: Based on your update, I am not aware of any API access to that information.

Comment: It doesn't look like such a feature exists.  A similar question was asked, and an idea was discussed here:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625069/ruby-aws-programmatically-generate-list-of-available-aws-instance-types