# List AWS instance types using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I need to list all the instance types that are provided by AWS using boto. I could've used a static list of instances but it doesn't seem a good solution because the instance types might change in future.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019681/getting-a-complete-list-of-ec2-instances-available-in-aws-by-any-api-or-json-req

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no official API call to retrieve **Instance Types** available in each region.

However, you can retrieve and parse the [AWS Price List API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/price-changes.html), which is really a set of **static JSON/CSV files** that contain pricing for each Instance Type in each Region.

You'll be amazed at how many pricing combinations there are -- the master EC2 price file is 130MB!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're looking for, http://www.ec2instances.info/ has a CSV of the basic machine types.  It is **not** an official Amazon reference.  However, I've found it to be kept up to date very well.  This information certainly does change but not so often that you couldn't live with a static list for a little while.